# Azure resourcemanager billing doesn't work

Tags: java, azure, billing

I'm trying to get my account billings via Java and I used sample from azure documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/resourcemanager-billing-readme?view=azure-java-preview
But, this solution seems not working, because I see this picture in debug mode:
[image]

All entities in the object f are null and innerClient throws this exception :
`Method threw 'com.azure.core.http.rest.MissingRequiredAnnotationException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.azure.resourcemanager.billing.implementation.$Proxy5.toString()`.

Then I tried to use Consumption librariry to get billing data and got exact the same situation:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/resourcemanager-consumption-readme?view=azure-java-preview
```

[image]

All entities show null and elements from innerObject throw this exception:

```
Method threw 'com.azure.core.http.rest.MissingRequiredAnnotationException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.azure.resourcemanager.consumption.implementation.$Proxy14.toString()
```

My pom file:

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>AzureConsumption</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.resourcemanager</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-resourcemanager-consumption</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-identity -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-core-http-netty -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-core-http-netty</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Any ideas how to fix it? Or what I'm doing wrong?